# Adding exceptions to a TitleCase Method C#

Tags: c#, methods, title-case

I have the following code which will convert a string to TitleCase. 
I would like to create an exception to this, so that if the string entered, finds the exact characters in sequence, it will ignore it and proceed to convert the rest of the string. eg. if part of the string contains: ABC I want to ignore this as a rule and proceed to convert the rest of the string in TitleCase:

```
public string ConvertToTitleCase(string input)
    {
        char[] chars = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(input.ToLower()).ToCharArray();

        for (int i = 0; i + 1 < chars.Length; i++)
        {

            if ((chars[i].Equals('\'')) ||
                (chars[i].Equals('-')))
            {
                chars[i + 1] = Char.ToUpper(chars[i + 1]);
            }
        }
        return new string(chars);
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: are you using the word `Exception` improperly? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173160(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: I dont quite know what you are trying to do here. Do you want to throw an exception when the string contains "ABC" or filter the options with ABC

Comment: @vulkanino - There is more than one meaning to the word outside of programming `A person or thing that is excluded from a general statement or does not follow a rule.`

Comment: @Jamiec it is not clear what he wants to do, if he wants to throw an (programming) Exception or if he wants to create an exception to the generic convertion rule.

Comment: @vulkanino Obviously, I didn't mean (programming) Exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all you need

```
       private string ConvertToTitleCase(string input, string ignore) {
            var lcSB = new StringBuilder();
            var lcStart = 0;
            while (lcStart < input.Length) {
                var lcNext = input.IndexOf(ignore, lcStart);
                if (lcNext < 0)
                    lcNext = input.Length;
                lcSB.Append(input.Substring(lcStart, lcNext - lcStart).ToUpper());
                if (lcNext < input.Length)
                    lcSB.Append(ignore);
                lcStart = lcNext + ignore.Length;
            }
            return lcSB.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Georgy this is the code I used, although this had to be altered to slightly for what I was trying to achieve. If the string I entered was all in uppercase, (not including the special pattern: ABC) it would not convert to Title Case as it needed to be set to all lower case first. This is the code I altered to achieve what I required: 1. lcSB.Append(input.Substring(lcStart, lcNext - lcStart).ToLower());
2. return CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(lcSB.ToString());
Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

Normally what you do in situations like this is instead of enumerating char-by-char you break your string into parts (possibly by regex, or somehow, details are unimportant), process each part separately (capitalize the first character of each part) and join everything back.

All the exceptions in this scenario are just these "parts" you don't touch.

So the algorithm is:

- Break the string into tokens
- Enumerate tokens and process (or ignore if it is an exception)
- Join the tokens back to the string.

Good Luck :)

Comment: +1 agree. from the code maybe he wants to titlecase the source string, with two exception rules. rule one: if a character is escaped by a \ or a `-` then convert to uppercase. rule two: if the string contains a special pattern (say ABC), then keep that pattern uppercase.

Comment: Hi @vulkanino, yes this is what I am trying to accomplish. If the string that is entered has a special pattern eg. If the string that I enter into this method contains a sentence and one of the words in the sentence is: ABC in that exact order. I want the method to ignore this special pattern and proceed to the next word in the sentence. Sorry guys if I was not explaining this correctly.

Comment: Thank you all for the help with this, I am used to coding in VB, although in this case the original program has been written in C#. I wrote the title case method for this program, just got a bit stuck with adding certain rules to the method created. Thanks again people.

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this, using the `MatchEvaluator`

```
return Regex.Replace(input,
                     @"\S+",
                     (match) =>
                     {
                             var word = match.Value;

                             var formatException = yourListOfTitleCaseExceptions.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Trim().Equals(word, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

                                    if (formatException == null)
                                    {
                                        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(word.ToLower())
                                    }

                                    return formatException.Trim();

                                });
```

This will split the words up, check the list of exceptions you have made and ignore title-casing them. If the word isn't found, it will get title-cased as expected. If an exception is found, the un-touched word will be returned.